# Using Excel to Identify Entries that Add to a Specific Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large list of numbers and would like to identify the different combinations that add up to another certain amount. I have tried installing the solver add in but for some reason it won't appear in the Data tab.

Any other way to do this?

Comment: google `knapsack puzzle vba`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eva: There's some code at http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/10/27/which-numbers-sum-to-target/ that should be enough to get you started.